# rules for "prevent this page from creating additional dialogs"

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I try to understand Firefox's behavior regarding the added "prevent this page from creating additional dialogs" on dialog boxes.

Using jquery, if I add the following listeners :

```
//html
<input class="testInput" />

//javascript
$('.testInput')
.click(function(){ alert('clicked') })
.keyup(function(){ alert('keyup') })
```

1. When clicking on the input, the alert box appears normally, until the
   ~13th time.
2. When hitting a key, on the other hand, the second message box already
   appears with the message "prevent this page from creating additional
   dialogs". Actually, there seems to be some tiemout, and if I wait
   like 2 seconds between two keystrokes, the message disappears.

From my informal tests, `2.` actually applies whenever the alert box is not called from within a onclick callback (e.g : keyup callback, displaying an alert box in answer to an ajax action...)

I am using Firefox 9.0.1 under Ubuntu, as far as I know I haven't tweaked firefox's settings regarding these thresholds.
I imagine it happens with any recent version of any browser.

I am using the jQuery library, but I don't think it is relevant here.

My question is :
What are the exact rules which make this warning appear in a dialog box ?

[Edit]

Using Chromium/Ubuntu (version 17.0.963.26), the threshold seems to be only the delay between two dialog boxes.

You can test this from jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/9XwTn) (thx Rory McCrossan)

Comment: FYI: testing with this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/9XwTn/) I get the checkbox in the alert on the 12th iteration for both click and keyup.

Comment: @Rory : I still have my behavior. What browser do you have ? thx for the jsfiddle link.

Comment: Just to fill in with some more data input; I get it on the 12th click iteration and 2nd keyup iteration on FF 9.0.1 Windows XP SP3.

Comment: @LeGEC sorry forgot to mention browser, FF9.0.1 on W7 Pro x64

Comment: How to reset this ? Now I want the dialogs again !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exact rule(s): A timed interval between the dialog boxes popping up.
The value used to determine this is set in **SUCCESSIVE_DIALOG_TIME_LIMIT**

Check out line 2614 in the link below the snippet:

```
nsGlobalWindow::DialogOpenAttempted()

TimeDuration dialogDuration(TimeStamp::Now() - topWindow->mLastDialogQuitTime);

if (dialogDuration.ToSeconds() < Preferences::GetInt("dom.successive_dialog_time_limit",SUCCESSIVE_DIALOG_TIME_LIMIT)){topWindow->mDialogAbuseCount++;return (topWindow->GetPopupControlState() > openAllowed || topWindow->mDialogAbuseCount > MAX_DIALOG_COUNT);}topWindow->mDialogAbuseCount = 0; return false;}
```

[Link to source](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/0f872fecb5a8/dom/base/nsGlobalWindow.cpp)

Comment: And **what is this value** ?

Answer (score 1):

You can kick around the Firefox source if you like. Note that different browsers will have different rules.

The relevant code for Firefox is in [`nsGlobalWindow.cpp`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/base/nsGlobalWindow.cpp) and [`nsGlobalWindow.h`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/base/nsGlobalWindow.h) (the links below are to line numbers, and so will slowly rot as the source changes). It appears to be controlled by the constants [`MAX_DIALOG_COUNT`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/base/nsGlobalWindow.h#116) (10) in `nsGlobalWindow.h` and [`SUCCESSIVE_DIALOG_TIME_LIMIT`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/base/nsGlobalWindow.h#112) (3, units are seconds). `nsGlobalWindow.cpp` keeps a count (`mDialogAbuseCount`). Apparently, the [`dialogDuration`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/base/nsGlobalWindow.cpp#2611) function either increments or clears `mDialogAbuseCount` depending on whether the dialog has been open longer than the SUCCESSIVE_DIALOG_TIME_LIMIT. The [`AreDialogsBlocked`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/base/nsGlobalWindow.cpp#2628) function uses the `mDialogAbuseCount` (in part) to decide whether they're blocked.

So in short: If you're repeatedly opening pop-ups and then closing them within three seconds, after 10 or so you'll trigger something.